# Query result records to column for comparison

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table, field

Is there anyway to achieve displaying query results into columns and have the records go to the next row?

Here's my SQL table:

```
------------SQL TABLE -----------

    id   |    product_name    | product_type
    0    |    Lorem           | Table   
    1    |    Ipsum           | Chair
    2    |    Dolor           | Lamp
    3    |    Sit             | Chair
```

This is what I would like.

```
        Lorem    |  Ipsum      |    Dolor   |   Sit       |
------------------------------------------------------------
id    | 0        |  1          |    2       |   3         |
type  | Table    |    Chair    |    Lamp    |    Chair    |
```

Desired output:

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
    <td>Dolor</td>
    <td>Sit</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>Table</td>
    <td>Chair</td>
    <td>Lamp</td>
    <td>Chair</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

This is my code, but I know this is terribly wrong. I'm just stuck on how to make a new row for a field if that makes sense using while and for loops.

```
    echo '<table><tr>';

        $i=1;

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<td><table><tr><th>'.$rows['product_name'].
            '</th></tr><tr><td>'.$rows['product_id'].
            '</td><td>'.$rows['product_type'].'</tr></table></td>';
                if($i %2 == 0) { 
        echo '</tr>
                <tr>'; }
                }    
        echo'
        </tr>
        </table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rotate your data.
You could use something like this (untested):

```
// build query
$query = "SELECT id, product_name, product_type FROM whatevertableyouhave";

// query the database
$result = mysql_query($query);

// cols we are interested in (from the SQL query)
$cols = array(
  'id',
  'product_name',
  'product_type';
);

// initialize rotated result using cols
$rotated = array();
foreach($cols as $col) {
  $rotated[$col] = array();
}

// fill rotated array
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
  foreach($cols as $col) {
    $rotated[$col][] = $row[$col];
  }
}

// echo html
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($cols as $col) {
  echo "<th>{$col}</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach($rotated as $col => $values) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($values as $value) {
    echo "<td>" . htmlentities($value) . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is much closer to what I need. One thing though, I need the product name to be the column header. I've been messing around with the code but how do you get the `value => product_name` as `$col`?

Comment: ok, I figured it out. i just took out `foreach($cols as $col) {
  echo "<th>{$col}</th>";` and added this code within `while` loop
 `$name = $row['product_name'];
  echo '<th>'.$name.'</th>';` Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Bonus tip: if you're just starting with PHP / MySQL, please take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions, both of which are better alternatives to the naive mysql_* functions. Especially take a look at parameterized queries, which are a great way of preventing SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      echo '<table>';


    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<tr><th>'.$rows['product_name'].
        '</th></tr><tr><td>'.$rows['id'].
        '</td></tr><tr><td>'.$rows['product_type'].
        '</td></tr>';

            }    
    echo' </table>';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I actually tried this solution before coming here. The results just display in one column as opposed to starting a new column at a new product name.

Comment: yes but you said like that in your exemple . product name in one row as in your exemple

Comment: It displays results like this all in the same column: 

`product_name \n` 
`id \n`
`product_type \n`
`product_name \n` 
`id \n`
`product_type \n` | I need it to display in several columns. like a product comparison table.

Comment: Thanks, it's still doing the same. In this line it is only giving one row instead of making a new column for the next record `echo '<table><tr>';` It is outside of the `while loop`

Comment: sorry, I don't think you understand what I mean.